# How to disable horizontal scrolling within virtualbox on Ubuntu guest, Windows 7 host?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-9.10, virtualbox, x-windows, scroll-wheel

I am using Windows 7 as Host, Ubuntu Karmic as guest OS with guest tools installed and I get an annoying glitch when switching from host to the guest machine: Vertical scrolling switches to horizontal! (using the mouse wheel). Since I don't really care about horizontal scrolling, how can I disable this?

I have checked the web and the only thing I found was to play in the xorg.conf file and adding in the section "InputDevice"

```
Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
```

which would enable vertical scrolling only. The thing is, I don't have that section in my config file so I guessed that I would need to add

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier "VBoxMouse"
    Driver "vboxmouse"
    Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection
```

But that does not seem to work after restarting xserver.

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a little workaround that I posted on stackoverflow's duplicate question [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533299/how-to-disable-horizontal-scrolling-within-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-guest-windows-7/2693238#2693238). A virtualbox [bug][2] is basically behind all this. Quoting from my own answer from stackoverflow if you don't want to go on the website:

> Well since the the ZAxisMapping should
>   already disable the horizontal
>   scrolling in my question, but of
>   course did still not seem to work, I
>   have found that it was actually a
>   virtualbox bug that has something to
>   do with the ALT key modifier.
>   Basically the scrolling will switch
>   from vertical to horizontal if the ALT
>   key is pressed at the same time as
>   falling into the virtualbox window.
>   This happened to me because I was
>   using dexpot in Win7 with the desktop
>   switching feature using the alt key.
>
> Until the bug is corrected, the
>   workaround is after getting into the
>   vbox window and noticing that
>   scrolling was switched to horizontal,
>   you need to hit the host key, hit ALT
>   again, then manually click the vbox
>   window to return to it, without
>   touching the alt button. For now, I do
>   not use the alt key for switching
>   desktops, and everything works fine
>   again.

Comment: Cool I get to vote you up on two stack sites!!

Answer (score 1):

I had solved this problem  by hitting top options of VM

`view -> Auto-resize Guest Display`

Comment: This option is disabled for me. How and where to enable it?